# WoW - why improve Inscription after 600?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What advantages of Inscription at 700 comparing to Inscription at 600?

According to [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/skill=773/inscription#recipes:550+16+1) there are no recipe, which needs Inscription above 600.

I heard that war paints became cheaper, but I would like to know exact dependence "costs vs Inscription level".
And aren't there any other advantages?

P.S. I heard that the yield  for war paint increases from 4 paints per 10 pigments up to 10 per pigments, when inscription level increases up to 700. If one suppose linear dependence, and that at lvl600 you get 4 paints, that at lvl617 you must have 5, 633->6, 650->7,667->8,684->9,700->10. But this is not the case, my hero at 640 level and can create only 4 paints from 10 pigments.
P.S2. I have lvl700 inscription now, but my ability to create paints is limited to 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Warlords of Draenor all new profession recipes are usable with a skill of one in the profession. The only difference is in the daily cooldowns for the professions.

For Inscription this is [War Paints](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=169081/war-paints):

> Additional paints are created when your Inscription skill is 600 or higher.

Up to skill level 600 you generate 4 War Paints per use, until level 700 this increases to 10 War Paints per use. This scales more or less linearly, you get 5 with skill 600 and one more with every 20 additional skill points with some random variation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about "costs vs Inscription level" function. Or you are saying that up to 699 you get only 4 War Pints per use, and at 700 the price drops down immediately to 10?

Comment: I added the scaling for additional War Paints.

Comment: thank you, but at least "you get 5 with skill 600" is incorrect. I have 4 with skill 615.

Comment: There's a small bit of random variation in the number you get, until you reach 700.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I got to lvl 634 and still have 4 paints, I wouldn't call it small!

Comment: I just did a round of daily profession cds (not all inscription) and got the amount from my answer in 4 out of 5. One had 6 were it "should" be 7. You are either very unlucky or there may be a difference from other professions. My research covered all professions since there should be no difference.

Comment: @Raidri, can it be connected to hero level? I have 96 only.

Comment: It should not. My chars were of different levels.

Comment: After 600, you can get anywhere between 4 and 10. At 700, you're guaranteed 10 (but you are not guaranteed any primals, these are always random).

Comment: @originaluser, this is also incorrect. I have 700 now, but still can create only 4 paints.

Comment: @klm123 That sounds like a bug. I have always got 10 with skill 700. Try opening a support ticket ingame and ask for clarification there. Something is strange here.

Comment: @Raidri, well... support told me that this is not bug, I am just unlucky......

Comment: @klm123 I also cannot recall ever creating less than 10 of my profession item at 700 skill, and I have 12 100s with maxed professions. Maybe I have been super lucky for the past several months? But I can't help but feel that GM is wrong, and you have a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage I can see outside of the increased War Paints is to meet the criteria of the [Grand Master of All](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=9087/grand-master-of-all) achievement (raise each primary profession to 700).

Answer (score 1):

First, I just levelled up my inscription to 700.

Then, in "Inscription window" I still see that I can create 4 paints using 10 pigments.
But as a matter of fact, when I run transformation I get 10 paints.

Also, I contacted support, and been explained that even at lvl700 you are **not guaranteed** to get 10 paints for 10 pigments. But when you run transformation you have a chance get additional paints over mentioned 4.

So I conclude, that with leveling up inscription you:
1. Get new achievements, like [Ben](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221815/49789) told.
2. Increase your chance to create more that 4 war paints per cast.